# Trouble with sockjs or dependencies in Angular

Tags: angular, webpack, sockjs

I cant get any request from an Observable subscription in Angular. The service stars and keep active but there is not new readers, in the browser console i cant see something that seems an error, but i cant identify the reason

```
SockJS
SockJSClient
initSocket
(anonymous)
./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/index.js?http://0.0.0.0:0/sockjs-node&sockPath=/sockjs-node
__webpack_require__
0
__webpack_require__
checkDeferredModules
webpackJsonpCallback
```

in package-lock.json the dependencia seems right

```
"sockjs": {
  "version": "0.3.19",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/sockjs/-/sockjs-0.3.19.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-V48klKZl8T6MzatbLlzzRNhMepEys9Y4oGFpypBFFn1gLI/QQ9HtLLyWJNbPlwGLelOVOEijUbTTJeLLI59jLw==",
  "dev": true,
  "requires": {
    "faye-websocket": "^0.10.0",
    "uuid": "^3.0.1"
  }
},
"sockjs-client": {
  "version": "1.3.0",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/sockjs-client/-/sockjs-client-1.3.0.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-R9jxEzhnnrdxLCNln0xg5uGHqMnkhPSTzUZH2eXcR03S/On9Yvoq2wyUZILRUhZCNVu2PmwWVoyuiPz8th8zbg==",
  "dev": true,
  "requires": {
    "debug": "^3.2.5",
    "eventsource": "^1.0.7",
    "faye-websocket": "~0.11.1",
    "inherits": "^2.0.3",
    "json3": "^3.3.2",
    "url-parse": "^1.4.3"
  },
```

.

Comment: please share your code well, provided information is not enough.

Comment: Thanks for your time. The think is that the api rest server didnt have a socket response configuration. Totally my fault

Answer (score 0):

The api rest server need a sockets response configuration